# Tridion vs Wordpress as a CMS

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-manager

I have been tasked with presenting to our business partners a case for converting their CMS from WordPress to SDL Tridion 2013 SP1.  I have found a few useful links describing/reviewing the different CMS products, but I was hoping someone could lay out a few key differences between WordPress and Tridion.  My initial investigation suggests that Tridion is a more robust, scalable application, but having never used WordPress, I was hoping for some specific differences between the 2 CMS's that I can highlight as a possible reason to switch to Tridion.

Comment: You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. Which is why I will decide to close this question right now.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a wrong place to seek an answer to question like this. But it seems that you have already answered your question: "*Tridion is a more robust, scalable application*"

The most important question that people overlook while looking for a CMS is that your CMS must be able to grow with your business and evolving requirements.

This a very nice [article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/05/10-things-to-consider-when-choosing-the-perfect-cms/) which I came across when I started to compare CMS. Hope it helps.